# How can bash script become zombie?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, process, zombie-process

I have bash script which starts some childs using this command:

```
 ./run_task.sh 2>&1 &
```

At some point child task become zombie and i have no idea why this happens.
As far as i know shell will invoke **wait** for child processes on its own,
so it's not required to manually call **wait** for bash script child.
Child doesn't call any exec (but call some C++ binaries synchronously).

Whatever i try i cannot reproduce such behavior.
Is there any way to make bash script a zombie?

Bash:

> GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

System:

> "RedHatEnterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)" 7.9 Maipo

EDIT:
The parent at the moment child becomes zombie is running, so this child will be zombie forever since it doesn't get bound to init process

Comment: Try `nohup ./run_task.sh 2>&1 &`.  But make sure your run_task.sh script ends at some point and does not have something hanging up (ex. infinite loop).

Comment: But nohup daemonise task so it will be parented to systemd on exit and waited just fine